Is there an easy way to table table data in html and convert it into word press posts?
I have a table with 150 entries written in HTML. I want to convert each table entry into a WordPress post so that I can make it searchable using Posts Table with Search plugin.  Is there an easy way to generate these posts in WordPress or will I have to do it manually?

You may want to check out WP All Import plugin
